# Copying Python script in rootfs with buildroot

Tags: python, linux, buildroot

I'm trying to include my Python scripts in my Linux image (for Raspberry Pi). I have 11 scripts and I would like to have them in a file who looks like:
/app/scripts/all_my_python_scripts.py
Thanks to that, I will be able to call script after boot time to start daemon automatically.

Currently, I am having these .mk and Config.in files in /path-to-buildroot/buildroot/package/python-scripts :

Config.in

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON_SCRIPTS
    bool "python-scripts"
    default "y"
    help
      Import all Python (3.7.2) scripts
```

python-scripts.mk

```
PYTHON_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_VERSION = 1.0
PYTHON_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_SOURCE = ../../scripts/
PYTHON_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_LICENSE = BSD-3-Clause
PYTHON_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_TYPE = distutils

define PYTHON_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_COPY
    @$(call MESSAGE,"Syncing python scripts to $(TARGET_DIR)")
    cp ../../scripts/* $(TARGET_DIR)/scripts/
endef
$(eval $(generic-package))
```

I tried to modify the source path and the "generic-package" but still the same issue. I also correctly update buildroot/package/Confin.in and I double-checked with make menuconfig.
I am currently trying to tar my python scripts (before compilation) store them in buildroot/dl and exact them via the makefile, but it doesn't sound logic at all ... I suppose an easier way exist.

Sometime buildroot try to download some file ... sometime it compiling but nothing happen. However, I notice I can't see my 'call MESSAGE', I am missing something ...

Answer (score 2):

First, the prefix of variables in the .mk file must have a prefix equal to the
file name, without '`.mk`', uppercased and with underscores instead of dashes:

- `PYTHON_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_VERSION` -> `PYTHON_SCRIPTS_VERSION`
- `PYTHON_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_SOURCE` -> `PYTHON_SCRIPTS_SOURCE`
- etc

Additionally there's no "COPY" step in Buildroot, so the variable `PYTHON_SCRIPTS_COPY` is ignored.
You probably want to use the "INSTALL" step:

- `PYTHON_PYTHON_SCRIPTS_COPY` -> `PYTHON_SCRIPTS_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS`

Finally, the "SCRIPTS_TYPE" step is specific to the Python package infrastructure. Since you are using the generic package infrastructure that variable will be ignored.

---

Note: a completely different solution if you just need to copy files in your rootfs is to use a root filesystem overlay (`BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY`). It's simpler, check it out and see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem, it was variable name issue, I rename PYTHON_SCRIPTS in SCRIPTS, below the correct Makefile:

buildroot/package/scripts/scripts.mk

```
    ################################################################################
#
# scripts
#
################################################################################

SCRIPTS_VERSION = 1.0
SCRIPTS_DEV_DIR = ../scripts/
SCRIPTS_SITE = ../scripts
SCRIPTS_SITE_METHOD = local
SCRIPTS_INSTALL_TARGET = YES

define SCRIPTS_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    rm -v $(TARGET_DIR)/scripts/*
    rsync -av $(SCRIPTS_DEV_DIR) $(TARGET_DIR)/scripts/
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```